# Получение значения href при парсинге

Tags: php, парсер, dom

Делаю парсер при помощи **Symfony/Domcrawler** и есть необходимость получить значение href некоторых элементов. Как это сделать?

```
<a class="Place__headerLink Place__title
            Link Link--shade-80 h5 small Place--lineClamping" href="https://club-drozdy.relax.by/" target="_blank" title="Drozdy Club" data-reactid=".yfuzkhv2j8.5.0.0.1.0.0.$10336959.2.1.0.0.0.0">Drozdy Club</a>
```

А так я получаю само значение

```
$crawler->filter('div.PlaceList__itemWrapper:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(2) > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1) > a:nth-child(1)');
```

Comment: код то ваш где?

Comment: Добавил кусок HTML'a. Из которого необходимо взять

Comment: и что там, `->attr('href')` или `->link()->getUri()` не работают? или у вас и сам поиск нужного элемента `null` возвращает?

Comment: `->attr('href')` всё как надо делает. Я похоже невнимательно документацию смотрел)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Согласно [документации](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dom_crawler.html#accessing-node-values) для доступа к атрибутам узлов используется метод `attr('attr_name')`

> Access the attribute value of the first node of the current selection:
>
> ```
> $class = $crawler->filterXPath('//body/p')->attr('class');
> ```

то есть в данном случае, `attr('href')`.

[На той же странице описано](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dom_crawler.html#links) взаимодействие со ссылками, а также приведен пример использования вспомогательного [класса `Link`, с его методом `getUri`](http://api.symfony.com/3.3/Symfony/Component/DomCrawler/Link.html#method_getUri). Пример использования тут примерно такой:

```
$nodeCrawler->filter('a')->link()->getUri(),
```